# How to customize reponse in cloudformation for apigateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I have following configuration for my `GET` method in apigateway template for cloudformation

```
      "paths": {
        "/customer/{customerid}": {
          "get": {
            "description": "Returns JSON customer objects from DynamoDB.",
            "parameters": [
              {
                "required": true,
                "type": "string",
                "name": "customerid",
                "in": "path"
              }
            ],
            "produces": [
              "application/json"
            ],
            "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
              "passthroughBehavior": "never",
              "responses": {
                "default": {
                  "statusCode": "200"
                }
              },
              "uri": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                  ":",
                  [
                    "arn",
                    "aws",
                    "apigateway",
                    {
                      "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                    },
                    "dynamodb",
                    "action/GetItem"
                  ]
                ]
              },
              "httpMethod": "POST",
              "requestTemplates": {
                "application/json": "{\n  \"TableName\": \"customer\",\n  \"Key\": {\n    \"customerid\": {\n      \"S\": \"$input.params('customerid')\"\n    }\n  }\n}\n"
              },
              "credentials": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                  "TableAccessRole",
                  "Arn"
                ]
              },
              "type": "aws"
            },
            "consumes": [
              "application/json"
            ],
            "responses": {
              "200": {
                "description": "200 response"
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

The api is being created perfectly, however, the response of the api is

```
{
  "Item": {
    "Name": {
      "S": "Alex"
    },
    "CustomerId": {
      "S": "123"
    }
  }
}
```

But I want this to be a simple json like

```
{
    "Name":"Alex",
    "CustomerId":"123"
}
```

I am looking at aws documentation, but i am unable to figure out which part of my configuration needs to be changed. I know that i have `input` variable that i can use to fetch data, but where and how, I am so lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your existing template uses the [`x-amazon-apigateway-integration`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions.html#api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration) [Swagger extension](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions.html), you can add a [`responseTemplates`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions.html#api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration-responseTemplates) object containing your response mapping template to the existing `default` [`response`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions.html#api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration-response) you've already defined:

```
"x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
  "passthroughBehavior": "never",
  "responses": {
    "default": {
      "statusCode": "200",
      "responseTemplates": {
        "application/json": "{\"Name\": \"$input.path('$.Item.Name.S')\", \"CustomerId\": \"$input.path('$.Item.CustomerId.S')\"}"
      }
    }
  },
  [...]
```